# Unable to inject instance variable using dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am creating the new class manually without injecting through dagger, but all the instances variable in that class should be injected through dagger.
For Example:

```
 class TestingClass constructor() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var test: Test

    fun testing() {
        test.doSomeThing()
    }
}

class Test @Inject constructor() {

    fun doSomeThing() {

    }
}
```

```
TestingClass().testing()
```

I am trying to achieve the above scenario, but it throws error

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property test has not been initialized
```

Is it possible to achieve this scenario, Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please share your dagger Module/Component and the method injecting your `TestingClass` object. You don't seem to inject `test`.

Comment: Yet no Module or Component. You can't use dagger without a @Component class. Try starting over from a tutorial example.